# How to switch between pages while using facet_multiple( or facet_grid_paginate) function in R Shiny?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, facet, ggforce

I am using facet_grid_paginate function of "ggforce" package to plot facets ( around 80 ). 
`ggplot(Data, aes(x=Date,y=Avg_unit_price), size = 3) + geom_smooth() + facet_grid_paginate( ~Item, ncol = 3, nrow = 2)`

Plots are distributed on multiple pages but in the app, I can only see the last page and am unable to navigate between pages in R shiny app.

[image]

Apart from the above query, when I was trying to plot all the facets on a single page then the dimension of individual plot was extremely small. Is there any way we can control the dimension of each plot using facet function of ggplot package.

Comment: The default bahavior of facet_XXX_paginate() is to plot the last PAGE. If you want to plot another page you have to use the argument page = #, to see that exact page of your facets.
I suspect that on  a shiny app you will need to create page by page in a for loop to display them